# Rabbit VCS stopped working after upgrade to 11.10

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, svn, rabbitvcs

Been using RabbitVCS for months now happily. Then when I updated to Oneric on Monday Rabbit VCS stopped working.

It is installed but the right click menu in nautilus is gone and unintsalling/reinstalling does nothing. It sees to be available from the command line but the GUI seems to have vanished.

Comment: pretty sure it's due to [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus-python/+bug/859104) so I don't think a fix is available yet.

Comment: created http://code.google.com/p/rabbitvcs/issues/detail?id=602

Comment: @kikixx I think your right. And it will probably be a while before it is. Now I gotta go through the hassle of re-installing 11.04 or maybe I'll even go pre-unity to 10.10 - getting nostalgic for a version that just works...

Comment: Just found this: http://blog.rabbitvcs.org/archives/293/comment-page-1 from back in February

Comment: I added this to my post, but see also [this mailing list post](http://groups.google.com/group/rabbitvcs/browse_thread/thread/e2ac1f7360e5ea1f) — there should be a release soon (ping @AbdelOlakara)

Comment: For the OP and @AbdelOlakara — there are packages for [Oneiric in the PPA](https://launchpad.net/~rabbitvcs/+archive/ppa?field.series_filter=oneiric) :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update:** I've now uploaded the [packages to the PPA](https://launchpad.net/~rabbitvcs/+archive/ppa?field.series_filter=oneiric).

**Update:** See [this mailing list post](http://groups.google.com/group/rabbitvcs/browse_thread/thread/e2ac1f7360e5ea1f) — there should be a release soon.

I'm the packager for RabbitVCS, and I can confirm that @kikixx is correct — the changes in the Nautilus/Python bindings to v1.0 require a bit of work before the extension is usable in Ubuntu 11.10.

Adam is working on this, but he's not quite there yet (as evinced by the reports of those running the extension out of SVN). Once it's working, we'll have it up in [our testing PPA](https://launchpad.net/~rabbitvcs/+archive/rabbitvcs-testing). I honestly don't know how long that'll take though.

Comment: I can't install it from the PPA, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/82882/cannot-install-rabbitvcs-from-ppa-in-oneiric. If that problem is not on your side, sorry for bothering.

Answer (score 1):

Update to work with nautilus 3.0

http://groups.google.com/group/rabbitvcs/browse_thread/thread/267555d83c158923

Release announchement, its not in PPA yet, but you can download it manually here.