# Upgrading to 11.10 broke RabbitVCS

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, svn, rabbitvcs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rabbit VCS stopped working after upgrade to 11.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68587/rabbit-vcs-stopped-working-after-upgrade-to-11-10)

After the upgrade to 11.10, I no longer have file manager integration with RabbitVCS, which was the main goal of having this package. Is there anything I can do to fix it?

Alternatively, any good svn client with file manager integration would be acceptable, much like TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known problem](http://code.google.com/p/rabbitvcs/issues/detail?id=566) with rabbitvcs, as it needs to be updated to work with GNOME 3 libraries, along with a number of other nautilus plugins.