# How to determine all python-nautilus extensions in use?

Tags: nautilus, python, extension

I need to provide an application developer with a list of all other python-nautilus extensions I have installed/running (I am trying to provide information on [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/rabbitvcs/issues/detail?id=612)).

What is the easiest way to get a list of these extensions on my machine?

(Please tag this with "python-nautilus")

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rabbit VCS stopped working after upgrade to 11.10](http://askubuntu.com/questions/68587/rabbit-vcs-stopped-working-after-upgrade-to-11-10)

Comment: @hhlp my question does originate in a (happily resolved) rabbitvcs issue, but I'm asking the question so that other users of `python-nautilus` extensions can provide info if they encounter similar bugs - when I have a moment I'll clarify the question to make this clearer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update 2021: On newer versions, such as 20.04, have a look into

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nautilus/extensions-3.0/
```

but this does not contain Python extensions, but in there is a file `libnautilus-python.so`.

According to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109424/user-extension-location-for-nautilus-3) answer, you should also have a look in these directories in your home directory:

```
~/.local/share/nautilus-python/extensions/
~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts
```

Still found these directories on my v14.10, and on my v20.04.

User *hhlp*'s answer already says that  the system folders were (for older Ubuntu versions):

```
/usr/lib/nautilus/extensions-2.0/python 
/usr/lib/nautilus/extensions-3.0/python
```

It seems  to me that these no longer exist on my 20.04.

Answer (score 2):

you can find them in two directory :

```
/usr/lib/nautilus/extensions-2.0/python 

/usr/lib/nautilus/extensions-3.0/python
```

hope it help...

Comment: thanks! I found .so files in the extensions directory (including libnautilus-python.so) but no "python" directory - what does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 23.10 I found the extensions in these folders:

```
/usr/share/nautilus-python/extensions
~/.local/share/nautilus-python/extensions/
```

The first folder contains globally installed extensions, the second folder contains extensions only installed for the current user.

I would also note that extensions in these folders could have been installed through different means, so consider this before changing anything:

- System packages e.g. `sudo apt install nautilus-admin`
- Python e.g. `pip install` command
- Manually copying a `.py` file
- Running an install script which copies files there

*(I needed to find these folders in order to delete old incompatible extensions causing Nautilus to fail to open after upgrading my distro and gnome version)*