# User extension location for Nautilus 3

Tags: nautilus

Where (under my home directory) do I put Python extensions for Nautilus 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the source](http://git.gnome.org/browse/nautilus-python/tree/examples/README?id=1ff65f8a4c86bd20bafd3405ec35bc52b6a2275b), it's:

```
~/.local/share/nautilus-python/extensions/
```

Answer (score 1):

With nautilus 3.6 I did this:

Put the script into

```
~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts
```

and make it executable.

Answer (score 0):

#### May 2018 update

On Ubuntu 16.04 LTS this works for me:

```
$ ll /usr/share/nautilus-python/extensions/
total 32
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May 15 04:47 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Feb 20 18:36 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5165 Dec 28  2015 nautilus-admin.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5479 Apr  6 17:21 nautilus-admin.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5007 Oct 24  2015 nautilus-hide.py
```