# Cannot install RabbitVCS from PPA

Tags: 11.10, rabbitvcs

I'm trying to install RabbitVCS from its PPA ([required because of a bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68587/rabbit-vcs-stopped-working-after-upgrade-to-11-10)) but it won't:

```
# aptitude install rabbitvcs-nautilus
The following packages will be upgraded: 
  rabbitvcs-nautilus{b} 
1 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
Need to get 9,210 B of archives. After unpacking 4,096 B will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  rabbitvcs-nautilus: Depends: nautilus (< 1:3.0~) but 1:3.2.1-0ubuntu3.1 is installed.
                      Depends: python-nautilus (< 1.0~) but 1.0-0ubuntu2 is installed.
```

The solution aptitude offers it to remove about 100 core packages, which is of course not right.

Is there some way I can tell aptitude to just go ahead, try if it works with a slightly newer nautilus than specified. Or is there something else wrong and should it normally just work?

(I installed 11.10 when it was at RC level or something, but that shouldn't matter, right?)

---

Also, just to be sure, I tried `apt-get` as well.

```
# apt-get install rabbitvcs-nautilus
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 rabbitvcs-nautilus : Depends: nautilus (< 1:3.0~) but 1:3.2.1-0ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
                      Depends: python-nautilus (< 1.0~) but 1.0-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

But I haven't held any packages, at least not according to `aptitude search ~ahold`.

Comment: This is just an info more then answer, so I pass it here. There is an open bug about that: http://code.google.com/p/rabbitvcs/issues/detail?id=641

Comment: Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/77773/trouble-installing-rabbit-vcs-for-nautilus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu 11.10 uses Nautilus 3, so you need to install the `rabbitvcs-nautilus3` package, not `rabbitvcs-nautilus`.