# RabbitVCS suddenly stopped working in Nautilus

Tags: 11.04, nautilus, version-control, rabbitvcs

A while ago I installed RabbitVCS on Ubuntu 11.04. It then all worked pretty well, but since a few weeks (maybe even more than a month) RabbitVCS suddenly disappeared from the Nautilus context menu.

I visited this page: http://wiki.rabbitvcs.org/wiki/support/known-issues and saw some points I could try, but none of them worked out to a working version again.

Also this issue [Rabbit VCS stopped working after upgrade to 11.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68587/rabbit-vcs-stopped-working-after-upgrade-to-11-10) does not describe the solution for me, so I think it might be something else. I have also tried to reinstall RabbitVCS again from the PPA which was recently updated according to this [topic](http://groups.google.com/group/rabbitvcs/browse_thread/thread/267555d83c158923), but no luck.

I am still on 11.04 (as I don't like the way Ubuntu is going in newer versions at all) and my Nautilus version is 2.32.2.1 . Is there someone who can help with this one?

Comment: I don't know the answer but I recommend adding your issue to http://code.google.com/p/rabbitvcs/issues - be sure to include the version you are using and the source (repos, PPA, self-install) - good luck!

Comment: @d3vid Thank you, that's what I might do :)

Comment: The question was also posted on Google Code: http://code.google.com/p/rabbitvcs/issues/detail?id=633&sort=-id&colspec=Stars%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary

Comment: you can post that link as the answer to your question (and update it to "upgrade to RabbitVCS 1.X.Y" once the bug is resolved)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question has been posted to the development team on Google Code:

http://code.google.com/p/rabbitvcs/issues/detail?id=633